# Customise comment form look and feel

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 site and want to customize the comment form to always be plain text (regardless of the user and whether they are authenticated).  As the text format setting will be fixed, I want to remove the little blurb that appears at the bottom of the comment body.

In general, how do I go about customising the look and feel of the comment form?

UPDATE

As per Berdir's instructions I added an #after_build function.  I did this by adding a `hook_form_comment_form_alter` function to my template.php file.  That new function and the custom function it calls are below:

```
function mytheme_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id)
{ 
    $form['comment_body']['#after_build'][] = 'configure_comment_form';
    //$form['comment_body']['und']['#after_build'][] = 'configure_comment_form';
}

function configure_comment_form(&$form, &$param1, &$param2)
{
    var_dump($form);
}
```

Clearly I can tell that my `configure_comment_form` function is getting called as the `var_dump` gets printed out.  I've tried adding the `configure_comment_form` to the #after_build at both the location in the `$form` array shown in the code.  I get identical results for both, the comment body form field simply disappears.

I've not overwriting any existing after build functions.  `$form['comment_body']['#after_build']` does not exist when I add a function to it and `$form['comment_body']['und']['#after_build']` looks as below after adding the custom function:

```
["#after_build"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(30) "field_form_element_after_build"
        [1]=>
        string(22) "configure_comment_form"
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the filters box under the comment body you can use your theme's template.php to implement the following hooks:

```
function theme_filter_tips($variables) {
    return '';
}
function theme_filter_tips_more_info() {
    return '';
}
function theme_filter_guidelines($variables) {
    return '';
}
```

This just leaves the outline of the filter/tips box, and that can be taken care of in your theme's CSS with:

```
.filter-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

Although I am not sure if that will cause other functionality to break by hiding that class.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similiar for http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg

First, add an #after_build function to the body form field like this "'#after_build' => array('privatemsg_check_format_access')," (since you are altering a form, first check if there is already such a function then append it, don't override)

Then, in that function, you set #access of the format field to FALSE and force the #default_value to whatever you want. See [privatemsg_check_format_access](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.pages.inc/function/privatemsg_check_format_access/7-1)

Comment: I follow you.  I'll give this a go sometime in the next week and report back.

Comment: OK, My after_build function is getting called, I used the hook_form_comment_form_alter function to insert a additional after build function.  However, just setting the #after_build to include my custom function is causing the comment form body not to show up at all.  I've double checked that I'm not overwriting any other functions set in #after_build and I'm not...

Comment: That is because a #after_build function does not alter by reference, instead, you must return the altered structure. See the privatemsg example from above.